# Why input file is caching the old uploaded images?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have `bootstrap modal` popup that pops up to enable user to select images to upload, So when the user chooses images I have `javascript` function that add new `<div>` containing the filename, then the user click save to save the images on the database, every thing is working except the input file is caching the old images and uploading them again with the newly selected images.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="functionalUpdatePanel">
                <ContentTemplate>
    <button title="إضافة مرفق" data-toggle="modal" class="uploadAttach" data-target="#myModal" ></button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
                labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
                hidden="true"> </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">إضافة مرفق</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" />                  

                    <h5 style="margin-right:45%;font-weight:bold;font- 
                      size:1.2em">اختر المرفق</h5>             

                    <div class="uploadBtnDiv">


                        <input 
             style="cursor:pointer;opacity:0;width:100%;height:100%"  
                    title="اختيار مرفق" type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"   
                   multiple="multiple" />

                    </div>      

                    <br />
                    <br />

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button style="width:100% 
                    !important;" Text="حفظ" title="إرسال المرفق" CssClass="btn 
                    btn-success" runat="server" ID="btnUpload" 
                     OnClick="btnUploadClick"      />
                                                 </ContentTemplate>
                                                <Triggers>
                                                    <asp:PostBackTrigger 
                     ControlID="btnUpload" />
                                                </Triggers>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
             </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>


                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here is my java script function

```
  $(document).on('change', '#myFile:visible', function() {

    var files = $(this)[0].files;
    var newLine;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        newLine = "<div class='attach-line'>" +
                    "<div class='attach-name'>" +

            files[i].name.slice(0,25)+'...' +

            "<i    class='icon-trash remove attach-delete'></i>" +

                    "</div>" +
                      "<br/>"+   
                  "</div>";

        $("#myModal .modal-body").append(newLine);

        // Clone the file selector, assign the name, hide and append it
        $(this).clone().hide().attr('name', 'myFile[]').insertAfter($(this));

      }
      $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".attach-name").remove();
          });
});
```

and bellow is the code behind

```
 protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("AppId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Bytes", typeof(byte[]));
            dt.Columns.Add("ImgNames", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ImgType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DedicatedMemberId", typeof(int));


            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Request.Files[i] != null && Request.Files[i].ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    string fType = Request.Files[i].ContentType.Split('/')[1];
                    string fName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);
                    byte[] bytes = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[i].InputStream).ReadBytes(Request.Files[i].ContentLength);
                    dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(hfAppId.Value), bytes, fName,
                        fType, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["memberId"]));
                }
            }
            string outputStr = AppsOperations.UpdateAttach("إرفاق صورة جديدة", "الطلبات ", dt, User.Identity.Name);

            if (outputStr == "s")
            {

                string redirectStr = "AuditApp.aspx?seq=" + hfAttSeq.Value + "&&AppType=" + hfAppType.Value + "&&id=" + hfAppId.Value;
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('تم تحميل المرفق بنجاح');window.location='" + redirectStr + "';", true);

            }
            else if (outputStr == "f")

            {

                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "تعذر تحميل المرفق" + "')", true);

            }

        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: i share the front end ,java script and backend

Comment: _every thing is working except the input file is caching the old images and uploading them again with the newly selected images_ - do you mean by this that user adds and uploads file1, then adds and uploads file2 - without refreshing the page - and file1 is uploaded again? Could that do you think be because the file is still there in `myFile`? Perhaps you should remove it after it has been uploaded?

Comment: yes exactly,the user select one file , and when clicking upload it will upload the file selected adding the old files

Comment: So.. after uploading a file, shouldn't you remove it from the list?

Comment: do you mean i should dispose the div modal-body?what list you mean?

Comment: actually its duplication the images i could say adding to uploading the old images, i dont know why, maybe because i am putting fileupload inside updatepanel?i removed the upload control to be a direct child to the asp.net form with no avail

Answer (score 0):

i am able to find the answer, actually i use the same code in another page to cache images for the use so i removed this the bellow line from java script function

```
$(this).clone().hide().attr('name', 'myFile[]').insertAfter($(this));
```